# How to find a route between two stations in PROLOG

Tags: recursion, routes, prolog, predicate, transitive-closure

Sorry, I know this question comes up a lot but I've done so much research and I just can't figure out how to solve this problem. I have represented a tube map in PROLOG and need to write a predicate that returns all routes between two stations. I know I need to use recursion and have tried a bunch of different solutions but none are working. The facts I have are:

```
station('AL',[metropolitan]).%Aldgate on the Metropolitan Line
station('BG',[central]).%Bethnal Green on the Central Line
station('BR',[victoria]).%Brixton on the Victoria Line
station('BS',[metropolitan]).%Baker Street on the Metropolitan Line
station('CL',[central]).%Chancery Lane on the Central Line
station('EC',[bakerloo]).%Elephant & Castle on the Bakerloo Line
station('EM',[bakerloo,northern]).%Embankment on the Bakerloo and Northern Lines
station('EU',[northern]).%Euston on the Northern Line
station('FP',[victoria]).%Finsbury Park on the Victoria Line
station('FR',[metropolitan]).%Finchley Road on the Metropolitan Line
station('KE',[northern]).%Kennington on the Northern Line
station('KX',[metropolitan,victoria]).%Kings Cross on the Metropolitan and Victoria Lines
station('LG',[central]).%Lancaster Gate on the Central Line
station('LS',[central,metropolitan]).%Liverpool Street on the Central and Metropolitan Lines
station('NH',[central]).%Notting Hill Gate on the Central Line
station('OC',[bakerloo,central,victoria]).%Oxford Circus on the Bakerloo, Central and Victoria Lines
station('PA',[bakerloo]).%Paddington on the Bakerloo Line
station('TC',[central,northern]).%Tottenham Court Road on the Central and Northern Lines
station('VI',[victoria]).%Victoria on the Victoria Line
station('WA',[bakerloo]).%Warwick Avenue on the Bakerloo Line
station('WS',[northern,victoria]).%Warren Street on the Northern and Victoria Lines
adjacent('WA','PA').%Warwick Avenue is adjacent to Paddington
adjacent('PA','OC').%Paddington is adjacent to Oxford Circus
adjacent('OC','EM').%Oxford Circus is adjacent to Embankment
adjacent('EM','EC').%Embankment is adjacent to Elephant & Castle
adjacent('NH','LG').%Notting Hill Gate is adjacent to Lancaster Gate
adjacent('LG','OC').%Lancaster Gate is adjacent to Oxford Circus
adjacent('OC','TC').%Oxford Circus is adjacent to Tottenham Court Road
adjacent('TC','CL').%Tottenham Court Road is adjacent to Chancery Lane
adjacent('CL','LS').%Chancery Lane is adjacent to Lviverpool Street
adjacent('LS','BG').%Liverpool Street is adjacent to Bethnal Green
adjacent('FR','BS').%Finchley Road is adjacent to Baker Street
adjacent('BS','KX').%Baker Street is adjacent to Kings Cross
adjacent('KX','LS').%Kings Cross is adjacent to Liverpool Street
adjacent('LS','AL').%Liverpool Street is adjacent to Algate
adjacent('EU','WS').%Euston is adjacent Warren Street
adjacent('WS','TC').%Warren Street is adjacent to Tottenham Court Road
adjacent('TC','EM').%Tottenham Court Road is adjacent to Embankment
adjacent('EM','KE').%Embankment is adjacent to Kennington
adjacent('BR','VI').%Brixton is adjacent to Victoria
adjacent('VI','OC').%Victoria is adjacent to Oxford Circus
adjacent('OC','WS').%Oxford Circus is adjacent to Warren Street
adjacent('WS','KX').%Warrent Street is adjacent to Kings Cross
adjacent('KX','FP').%Kings Cross is adjacent to Finsbury Park
```

And the solution I have tried is:

```
route(From,To,Route) :-
   routeattempt(From,To,[From],Route),
   reverse(Route,route).

routeattempt(From,To,Inbetween,Route) :-
   adjacent(From,To),
   \+member(From,Inbetween),
   Route = [From|Inbetween].
routeattempt(From,To,Visited,Route) :-
   adjacent(From,Inbetween),
   Inbetween \== To,
   \+member(Inbetween,Visited),
   routeattempt(Inbetween,To,Inbetween|Visited],Route).
```

But it just returns false to any input. If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: The third line of the route/2 predicate says `reverse(Route,route).` That can't be right, the second `route` is a constant. You want to reverse `Route` into the output, so you need a `RouteOut` that appears in the output here.

Comment: There is also a syntax error in the last line: `routeattempt(Inbetween,To,Inbetween|Visited],Route).` has an unclosed list ternm

Comment: Also, put the comments "%Aldgate on the Metropolitan Line" as values into the facts: `station('FR',[metropolitan], "Finchley Road on the Metropolitan Line")`. then you can use them when printing later. At this point, nothing of `station/2` is used at all of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is confused.

In

```
route(From,To,Route) :-
   routeattempt(From,To,[From],Route),
   reverse(Route,route).
```

the idea is clearly for `routeattempt/4` to "find a route from `From` to `To` to be stored as a list of stations in `Route`. But what does argument 3, here `[From]` do exactly? It seems to be the list of visited stations, but do your really need it? You have `Route` already.

Now you have to subcases: either `From` or `To` are adjacent:

```
routeattempt(From,To,Inbetween,Route) :-
   adjacent(From,To),
   \+member(From,Inbetween),
   Route = [From|Inbetween].
```

or they are are not:

```
routeattempt(From,To,Visited,Route) :-
   adjacent(From,Inbetween),
   Inbetween \== To,
   \+member(Inbetween,Visited),
   routeattempt(Inbetween,To,Inbetween|Visited],Route).
```

In the first case (the base case), it is unclear why to check whether `From` is a member of `Inbetween`. Indeed, this will preclude finding any route between between two adjacent stations, because `route/3` will already have deposited `From` into the list `Inbetween`. And shouldn't the route between two adjacent stations not just be `[From,To]` instead of `[From|Inbetween]`?

In the second case, you go from `From` to `To` by waystation `Inbetween`, which is also not equal to `To`, and has not been visited yet. Okay. But you need to complete `Route` after the recursive call.

Try add a `format("Current route from ~w to ~w: ~w\n", [From, To, Route])` before `adjacent/2` and see what happens.